# PostgreSQL 10 Use different directories for config_file and data_directory

Tags: postgresql, redhat, systemd, postgresql-10

I want to start postmaster using /some/dir/postgresql.conf and have the data /in/another/directory.

I have tried:

- Setting "Environment=PGOPTS='--config_file="/some/dir/postgresql.conf" in override.conf
- Setting "Environment=PGOPTS='--config_file="/some/dir/postgresql.conf" in postgresql.service
- Changing "ExecStart" in postgresql.service to start with -o "-c config_file='/some/dir/postgresql.conf'" (obsolete)

Setting -D /some/dir works and it uses postgresql.conf from correct path, but it does not respect data_directory and still uses the directory specified in -D.

```
postgres=# SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE setting LIKE '/%';
          name           |              setting
-------------------------+------------------------------------
 config_file             | /some/dir/postgresql.conf
 data_directory          | /some/dir
```

I have not been able to start postmaster in any way that shows different dir's for config_file and data_directory.

What's the correct way to start postmaster with configuration in one directory and make it read data_directory for where to locate the DBs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-D` option is (counter-intuitively) *not* the data directory, but the directory that contains `postgresql.conf`.  As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-postgres.html) says:

> **`-D datadir`**
>
> Specifies the file system location of the database configuration files.

Then you specify the data directory in `postgresql.conf` by setting the `data_directory` parameter.